# Server Process That Continues When Browser Is Closed

Tags: blazor, windows-services, windows-task-scheduler

I'm working on a project where I upload a couple of files to the server through a web interface using Blazor. I would like for a process to start running afterwards or when I click "process" that is independent of the browser window being open - e.g. I upload the files, click process and the server starts the processing and I can go do whatever I want. Initially, I thought maybe a windows service or task would be the most appropriate but is there a better solution? I suppose the files could be moved to a specific folder being watched and when the files are detected the process is started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use background tasks. Depending on the size and quantity of the files you could temporarily store them on the app and pick them up in intervals.

You can find docs needed here.
[Background tasks with hostedservice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

I have used hosted service in blazor to post files from memoery cache.

Comment: Thank you. Just seeing this now and reviewing the documentation at the link provided.

Comment: In order to manage the worker service from the Blazor server application, should the worker service be in the Blazor server project?

Comment: The hosted service have to be registered into the middleware pipeline in the BlazorServer program. Some way of persisting data to the worker is also needed. If you dont need to reuse the worker service somewhere else, then its a good idea to keep it in the same project as the BlazorServer.